# Teen/Young-adult sci-fi book about a man leaving Earth by order from an alien entity

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I read the book around 2006-2008 and it was aimed at teenagers. I read it in Swedish if that helps.

The story is set in the future and I think it begins with a man leaving Earth for a new job maybe. He is able to travel by himself in a spaceship of some sort.

I do not remember any of the names in the story unfortunately.

The parts I remember most are:

- The man is told by some sort of entity to meet a woman at a bar/restaurant, lika a space truckstop almost, that will join him on his travels. After she decides to join I believe they both can speak to the entity. It only talks to them via telepathy. I believe it visualises itself in their dreams or their minds as a ball of light.
- They travel together to a black hole or some other kind of wormhole and travel through to a new planet that the entity tells them to land on.
- They make use of tools the brought with them and the entity tells them how to do some basic things like hunt for food.
- They are not used to eating ordinary food so they get intense muslce pains in their jaws after chewing their food (cooked meat of some sort) for the first time.
- They get intimate, not describe in detail as far as I remember. They later have a child. I think the entity told them how to deliver the child. I think that humans aren't born in the traditional way on earth anymore so sex and reproduction isn't something as widely known. Or maybe it was just that childbirth is so assisted by advanced technology that the knowledge of doing it without the technology is lost.

The story ends with them living with their newborn child on this alien planet. I don't think it gives any continuation on them raising their child or continuing their life.

Comment: Finished the last sentence. Thank you for the heads up @Spencer

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: I thought I hit most points on that list. Are there any specific points you think I should add to @Valorum ?

Comment: Well, the name of the man, the age of the man, was the book set in the future (or an alternate present), was the sex described graphically / who was the book aimed at, the name of the aliens, what the aliens looked like, the name of the entity, the name of the woman, etc